# Error installing broadcom-sta-dkms

Tags: drivers, 22.04, broadcom

I have a xubuntu running from a USB stick, and recently updated to 22.04, but the upgrade failed to install the broadcom wireless drivers (which I need) and now I have a broken system that won't allow me to use wifi.

I have tried following the instructions [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=335744) but to no avail; installations of broadcom-sta-common and broadcom-sta-source are fine, but when I run `sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms` I get the following:

```
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
broadcom-sta-dkms is already the newest version (6.30.223.271-17).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-17) ...
Removing old broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 DKMS files...
Deleting module broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-46-generic
Building initial module for 5.15.0-46-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/broadcom-sta-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package broadcom-sta-dkms (--configure):
 installed broadcom-sta-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 broadcom-sta-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output in `/var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/build/make.log` is:

```
DKMS make.log for broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 for kernel 5.15.0-46-generic (x86_64)
Mon 15 Aug 15:55:34 BST 2022
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Makefile:89: Neither CFG80211 nor Wireless Extension is enabled in kernel
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-46-generic/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-46-generic'

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

make[1]: *** [Makefile:749: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-46-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:181: all] Error 2
```

I've no idea where or how I should run `make oldconfig && make prepare`.

Any advice? I'd really like **not** to have to perform a fresh install...

Comment: Try `bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: @Pilot6 this gives the same error:
`dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10`

Comment: @chili555 this is already installed.